# Callback for a recursive function which repeats unpredictable amount of times

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code (`home.js`):

```
angular.module("HomeApp", ["BaseApp"])
    .controller("MainCtrl", ["$http", "$window", "BaseService", function($http, $window, BaseService) {

        var self = this;
        BaseService.fetch.postsY(function() {
            self.cerrorMessages = BaseService.cerrorMessages;
        });
```

and this is BaseService:

```
angular.module("BaseApp", [])
    .factory("BaseService", ["$http", "$window", function($http, $window) {
        var self = this;
        self.posts = [];
        self.cerrorMessages = [];

        // Before you call self.accessErrors(), reset self.cerrorMessages.
        self.accessErrors = function(data) {
             for (prop in data) {
                 if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                     if (data[prop] != null && data[prop].constructor ==  Object) {
                         // Recursion used here.
                         self.accessErrors(data[prop]);
                     }
                     else {
                         self.cerrorMessages.push(data[prop]);
                     }
                 }
             }
         };

        self.fetch = {
             postsY: function(callback) {
                 $http.get('/postsY/')
                 .then(function(response) {
                     self.posts = response.data;
                     callback();
                 }, function(response) {
                     self.cerrorMessages = [];
                     self.accessErrors(response.data);
                     callback();
                 });
             }
         };
        return self;
    }]);
```

The problem is, in `BaseService.fetch.postsY`, if `$http.get('/postsY/')` returns an error, this is the code which executes:

```
self.cerrorMessages = [];
self.accessErrors(response.data);
callback();
```

What I'm worried of is if `callback()` is called before `self.accessErrors(response.data)` finishes setting `BaseService.cerrorMessages` because if that is the case, then the controller will set an incorrect, incomplete or empty `self.cerrorMessages`. How would I call the callback function after `self.accessErrors(response.data);` is done?

What I was thinking was was to call a callback function in `self.accessErrors` but `self.acessErrors` might call itself, so I need to be able to call the callback function when it is complete, which is hard to tell.

All I know is that `response.data` is a dictionary of key-value pairs where the value is either an array or another dictionary (and if it is another dictionary, that is when we call `self.accessErrors()` again).

Answer (score 0):

`self.accessErrors` is synchronous.  It will finish before `callback()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array, each time the executing of your loop starts, push a false to it, once done change it to true. This will give you indication if all started is finished.

```
var bools = []
recursive()
function recursive() {
    var index = bools.length
    bools.push(false)
    //  mark as started
    setTimeout(function{
        bools[index] = true
        //  mark as completed
        if (~bools.indexOf(false)) {
            //  this was the last one
        }
    }, Math.random()*1000)
    //  wait from 0 to 1s at random
    if (Math.random()>0.4) {
        recursive()
        //  N time repetition
    }
}
```

```
~-1 == 0
```